# C++ clock() only returns zero

Tags: c++, time

I've a programm in C++ with 2 functions and one main. The goal of the programm is to look which function takes more time.

PS: The code does the following: you enter a number "n" and the programm sums every number less or equal to "n" that are divisible by 5 or 3.

E.g. n = 15. Sum = 15+12+10+9+6+5+3 = 60

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    using namespace std;

    double Funktion(double Wert){
        double Summe = 0;
        int Index;
        bool Wiederholung;
        for(Index = Wert;Index >= 3;Index--){
            if(Index % 3 == 0)
            {
                Summe = Summe + Index;
                Wiederholung = false;
            }
            if(Index % 5 == 0 && Wiederholung == true)
            {
                Summe = Summe + Index;
            }
            Wiederholung = true;
        }
    return Summe;
    }

    double Funktion2(double Wert){
        double Summe = 0;
        int Abweichung1 = std::fmod(Wert,3);
        int Abweichung2 = std::fmod(Wert,5);
        int Abweichung3 = std::fmod(Wert,15);
        double Wert_3;
        double Wert_5;
        double Wert_15;

        Wert_3 = Wert - Abweichung1;
        Wert_5 = Wert - Abweichung2;
        Wert_15 = Wert - Abweichung3;

        Summe = (Wert_3+3)*((Wert_3/3)/2);
        Summe = (Wert_5+5)*((Wert_5/5)/2)+Summe;
        Summe = Summe-(Wert_15+15)*((Wert_15/15)/2);

        return Summe;
    }

    int main()
    {
        double Zahl;

        cout << "Welche Zahl wollen Sie aufsummieren lassen?: ";
        cin >> Zahl;

        clock_t t1;
        clock_t t2;

        double Rueckgabezahl;
        double Rueckgabezahl2;

        t1 = clock();
        Rueckgabezahl = Funktion(Zahl);
        t1 = clock()-t1;
        t2 = clock();
        Rueckgabezahl2 = Funktion2(Zahl);
        t2 = clock()-t2;

        cout << endl << std::fixed << "Aufsummierte Zahl (mit Loop): " << Rueckgabezahl << endl;
        printf("Zeit (in sek): %f", ((float)t1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

        cout << endl << endl << std::fixed << "Aufsummierte Zahl (ohne Loop): " << Rueckgabezahl2 << endl;
        printf("Zeit (in sek): %f", (float)t2/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    }
```

I've looked into multiple examples on how to establish a time counter via clock_t. First I established a clock_t t1, then I measured the time (tick) with t1 = clock() and then (after the function) I measured how many ticks the function took (with t1 = clock()-t1).

In other projects, this method works. But somehow in this particular code this is not the case. It always returns 0.00000.

What is my mistake?

If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Regards Q

Comment: `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` depends on your hardware, but on most systems nowadays it is a huge number. On the other hand your functions keeps your cpu busy only for a handful of tics

Answer (score 3):

A variable declaration in C++ does not take any time.
So, whether you write

```
t1 = clock();
double Rueckgabezahl;
t1 = clock()-t1;
```

or just `t1 = clock()-clock()` has the same outcome.

What you were most likely trying to measure is this:

```
clock_t t1, t2;
double Rueckgabezahl, Ruckgabezahl2;
t1 = clock();
Rueckgabezahl = Funktion(Zahl);
t1 = clock()-t1;
t2 = clock();
Rueckgabezahl2 = Funktion2(Zahl);
t2 = clock()-t2;
```

But even then, you won't get any impressive results either. There's barely anything for the CPU to actually do in your code, so you might need to use a higher resolution clock to get measurable results. Or, you know, loop your function code 100000 times or so. But even IF you do, since you cast your time to seconds before printing it... you'll STILL get 0 seconds as a result. You'll also have to turn optimizations off, because otherwise calling the method 100000 times will most likely have no effect as it's just optimized away.

As a side note: it's generally discouraged to use variable names that translate to keywords, such as 'Funktion' (~function). Also, you should probably switch to English names alltogether. I've never seen a project actually using German variable names and it just seems very odd to me, not to mention that it's a no-go if collaborating with other people who possibly don't speak it. Additionally (and this doesn't only apply to C++, variable names will generally either be camelCase (Java-style) or lower_case (C-Style). There's no definite one correct way and recommendations depend on the programming language, but you should always try to follow existing and common guidelines as best as you can.

Comment: Technically, "function" is not a *keyword*, though. But I definitely agree on the part that you should program in English. Also, it is very uncommon to start your functions and variables with a capital letter.

Comment: It is in many other languages however, such as java, javascript, php and many more.

Comment: Fair enough. It just sounds as if you were suggesting that it was a keyword in C++.

Comment: Alright and sorry for the German variables, didn't know it's annoying for others.

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn't show that `clock` is returning zero. It's the difference between your two measurements of `clock()` that is zero. You are measuring the time it takes to perform operations that take no time, which is less than 1 `clock` tick.

Imaging `clock()` returns `42` at `t1 = clock();`. The statement `double Rueckgabezahl;` takes no time at all, so `clock` will return the same value as it did just before. `t1 = clock()-t1;` will be equivalent to `t1 = 42 - 42;` which is where you get `t1 = 0;` from.

You can try using [`std::high_resolution_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) but you might not even be able to get a measurement then. You will be measuring how long it takes to read the clock.

Comment: Hi, yes I've done a dumb mistake the clocks should be around Rueckgabezahl = Funktion(Zahl); and Rueckgabezahl2 = Funktion2(Zahl);

Comment: But even if i do that, it still shows zero. Is it possible that an operation that calculates for-loops, mods etc. of a number like 6525263652 still only needs close to zero time?

Comment: No resolution can help, OP is calculating time in **seconds**.

Comment: ohhhhhhhh now i get it

Comment: `double Rueckgabezahl;` is a statement, not an expression.

Comment: @idmean Thanks.